# Android Radio Application-won't stop while using phone

Tags: app-inventor

I'm working in a radio station and I've been asked if i can do an android app for android users so they can listen live.
To be honest i know almost nothing, but with some tutorials i did a nice app android radio with **App Inventor**.

But there is also a big problem i would say which i couldn't find any tutorial how to fix it.
**If the radio is on, and I am getting a call** and start a conversation or if i do a call while radio is on, **the radio won't stop.**

So while I am talking on phone I also can hear live radio. And that is really annoying I can say. If someone can give me some advice would be awesome. with App Inventor i use block editor.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should begin by look for radio protocols.

Comment: [as already said in the forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/mitappinventortest/c3oPCzsfd_8), there is no solution for App Inventor Classic, you have to use App Inventor 2 instead.